# Include file in caffe .prototxt

Tags: caffe

I am building a siamese network from the example in [BLVC's site](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html)
there they use a simple convolutonal net to generate the features for the contrastive loss function, this is done by copy and pasting the .prototxt of each of the networks in the .prototxt of the final siamese network, the problem is I am using a much larger network, the .prototxt having about 5700 lines.
Is there a directive that allows me to tell it to just "include" that file in runtime? Something in the lines of "input" in LATEX so I don't have a 12k+ lines file.

Comment: [This question, and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44366735/5987698) might help.

Comment: you cannot just "include" a sub net twice. You need to rename the blobs and name all parameters with the same names.

Comment: I know, I have two similar files, one of which have the blobs renamed, but is there a way to avoid the copy-and-paste? How can I include the subnet?

Comment: @GoodDeeds That is in fact what I want to do, but I already have the net in a .prototxt and it's really huge, I wouldn't like to rebuild it in python, in the tutorial I mentioned they don't mind copy-and-pasting the network twice (with the blob's names changed) but I would like to avoid that, since the subnet I am using is so big

Comment: @VictorCapone If you already have the two copies, just put them in a single file and be done with it